# Entry Widget wont work properly in a function to call another module

Tags: python, tkinter

I am passing a Entry widget StringVal into a function that looks up what you type against another module. ie a1 = 123456.   when I type "a1" into the Entry widget, my function only returns "a1" and not its corresponding value of "123456".  I dont know how to get the def userd function to configure the label as 123456 rather than a1.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(App, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        a1 = 123456
        a2 = 456789
        a3 = 789456

        self.Userin = StringVar()

        self.user_input = Entry(self, insertwidth=0, width=30,
        textvariable=self.Userin)
        self.user_input.grid(row=2)
        self.user_input.insert(0, "0")

        self.bttn1 = Button(self, padx = 15, pady = 15, text = "Call A1",
        command = lambda: self.getdata(a1))
        self.bttn1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.bttn2 = Button(self, padx=15, pady=15, text="Call your entry",
        command=lambda: self.userd(self.Userin.get()))
        self.bttn2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.label = Label(self,bg = "white", padx = 35, pady = 25, text = "***")
        self.label.grid(row = 1)

    def userd(self,xxx):          
        self.label.configure(text = xxx)

    def getdata(self,row):
        self.label.configure(text = row)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x150")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Your function returns 'a1' because you never code anything else.

Add some conditions like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(App, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.a1 = 123456
        self.a2 = 456789
        self.a3 = 789456

        self.Userin = StringVar()

        self.user_input = Entry(self, insertwidth=0, width=30,
        textvariable=self.Userin)
        self.user_input.grid(row=2)
        self.user_input.insert(0, "0")

        self.bttn1 = Button(self, padx = 15, pady = 15, text = "Call A1",
        command = lambda: self.getdata(self.a1))
        self.bttn1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.bttn2 = Button(self, padx=15, pady=15, text="Call your entry",
        command=lambda: self.userd(self.Userin.get()))
        self.bttn2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.label = Label(self,bg = "white", padx = 35, pady = 25, text = "***")
        self.label.grid(row = 1)

    def userd(self,xxx):
        if xxx == "a1":
            self.label.configure(text = self.a1)
        elif xxx == "a2":
            self.label.configure(text = self.a2)
        elif xxx == "a3":
            self.label.configure(text = self.a3)

    def getdata(self,row):
        self.label.configure(text = row)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x150")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```